# ссориться vs. спорить

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление

**Please explain the difference between those two actions.**

My guess is that *спорить* is in some way more objective, sober and with the true wish to find a solution for a problem while the other is more an emotional quarrel.

Comment: This is actually one of many examples of different "semantic fields". For example - "кисть". Means "кисть руки" (a wrist? palm and fingers, basically) as well as "кисть для рисования" (paintbrush). However, I doubt that in English you can use a word "brush" to point any part of a hand.

Answer (score 7):

You're basically right.

*Ссориться*, however, might also mean "to fall out", to stop being friends. It does not necessarily mean being actively involved in a dispute or a quarrel.

Answer (score 4):

**Спорить = Argue**

Спорить doesn't mean to have more sober discussion at all. It can be heated or it can be calm. It means *to discuss* or *debate*.

However, **ссориться = quarrel, bicker or even brawl**, which always has negative connotation.

Answer (score 4):

Когда люди **ссорятся** - у них обязательно портятся отношения друг с другом. (Участники ссоры могут при этом *спорить*, а могут и не спорить).

Relationship between people who **quarrel** always becomes worse. (They may or may not *argue* while doing that)

Когда люди **спорят** - они имеют разные точки зрения относительно предмета спора.

When people argue - they discuss the subject while having different opinions on the subject. (They may or may not remain calm while doing that. When people *quarrel* they *never* remain calm.)

Answer (score 2):

Ссориться also means to separate with your ex, to spoil relations.
Мы с ней поссорились means We left each other.

Спорить has a merely debate meaning, not anything else.
But спорить на вещь is to have a bet on something.

Answer (score 1):

**Спорить** (people debate differing opinions)

"Спорю на 5 баксов, что выйдет по-моему." *5 bucks says it'll happen my way.*

Они спорят о мелочах. *They're splitting hairs.*

О вкусах не спорят. *One man's meat is another man's poison.*

---

**Ссориться** (people fight, feelings get hurt)

"Вы что, поссорились?" *Did you guys have a fight?*

"Давай больше не будем ссориться?" *Let's not fight anymore?*